# How to create an NSMutableArray and assign a specific object to it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, mkannotation

I am just getting into Obj C, and I am looking to create an array of MKAnnotations.

I have already created the MKAnnotation class called `TruckLocation` that contains the name, description, latitude, and longitude.

Here is what I have so far for the array:

```
NSMutableArray* trucksArray =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @[<#objects, ...#>]  nil];
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yore trying to combine 2 different syntaxes for similar but different things. You also don't seem to have any instances of your annotations.

Create some instances

```
TruckLocation *a1 = ...;
TruckLocation *a2 = ...;
```

Then we can add them

```
NSMutableArray *trucksArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:a1, a2, nil];
```

Or

```
NSMutableArray *trucksArray = [@[a1, a2] mutableCopy]
```

This is a shorter and more modern form but you need to make it mutable as it will create an immutable instance.

Comment: I don't understand the mutableCopy method. I've seen it around and it's cousin - the immutable copy of a mutable object. what's the purpose of copying and why is it so often seen with mutable arrays and dictionaries?

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs if you have an immutable object and you want to modify it you need to create a new object, that could either be with a convenience method or by making a mutable copy and editing it (usually if you want to make multiple modifications). You might immutable copy to keep a record of something you were given and protecting yourself against someone changing that object behind your back...

Answer (score 17):

Well:

```
NSString *a = @"a";
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:a,nil];
//or
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //alloc

[array addObject:a];
```

Answer (score 8):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:myObject];
```

Where myObject is the object of your custom class.

Answer (score 1):

Try something lke this

```
  NSMutableArray *annotationArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D shopPosition = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(allShopInfoObject.shopLatitudeValue, allShopInfoObject.shopLongitudeValue);

    MapAnnotation *mapAnnotation = [[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinates:shopPosition andTitle:allShopInfoObject.shopName andShopId:allShopInfoObject.shopId subTitle:@""];

        [annotationArray addObject:mapAnnotation];
[self.mapView addAnnotations:annotationArray];
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you initialize the objects and assign values the following way:

```
TruckLocation *truckLocationOne = [[TruckLocation alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation
           reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];
truckLocationOne.name = @"name";

TruckLocation *truckLocationTwo = [[TruckLocation alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation
           reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];
truckLocationTwo.name = @"name";
```

These objects would be added to the array temp in the following way:

1) 
`NSMutableArray temp = [[NSMtableArray alloc]initWithObjects:truckLocationOne,truckLocationTwo,nil];`

2) 
   `NSMutableArray temp = [[NSMtableArray alloc]init];
    [temp addObject:truckLocationOne];
    [temp addObject:truckLocationTwo];`

Hope this answers your query

Answer (score 0):

```
TruckLocation *loc1=...;
TruckLocation *loc2=...;
NSMutableArray *truckArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:loc1,loc2];
```

you can add objects at the time of initialization. by this you can add objects within the allocation code. also you can avoid more number of steps for writing with `addObject`.